# extjs treepanel filled with local data

Tags: json, extjs, tree, local, treepanel

I want to setup a treepanel with local data like this:

```
data =
{"root":
    {
     "08": {"field": "getCategory3()","name": "Untergruppe","object": "product"},
     "09": {"field": "getCategory2()","name": "Obergruppe","object": "product"}
    }
};
```

but im confused about how to get the data out of this string.

```
var mystore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: treemodel,
proxy: {
    data : data, 
    type: 'memory',
    reader: { type: 'json' }
},
});
```

How to create the model for this? Right now, no data is showing up in my tree

```
var treemodel = Ext.define('Task', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'object', type: 'string'},
]
});

var myTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',
{   xtype: 'treepanel', id: 'myTree',
    containerScroll: false,
    store: mystore,
    root: 'root',
    margin: '0 15 0 0',
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            appendOnly: true,
            sortOnDrop: true,
            containerScroll: true
        }
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty simple:

```
var txt = 'root: {
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        "id": "product",
        text: "product",
        "name": "product",
        leaf: false,
        children: [{
            "id": "08",
            text: "Untergruppe",
            "name": "getCategory3()",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            "id": "09",
            text: "Obergruppe",
            "name": "getCategory2()",
            leaf: true
        }, ]
    }, {
        "id": "shopproduct",
        text: "shopproduct",
        "name": "shopproduct",
        leaf: false,            
        children: [{
            "id": "04",
            text: "Lagerbestand",
            "name": "available_value",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            "id": "10",
            text: "Ust",
            "name": "getVAT()",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }, ]
}';

var data = Ext.decode(txt);

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: data
});
    Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a model for this. Look at [Ext.data.NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface). The fields and functions of this interface are applied to the Model used in the TreeStore. Unless you need more fields, you don't need a separate model.

Look at this jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/w4SjV/

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "detention", leaf: true },
            { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                { text: "algebra", leaf: true}
            ] },
            { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Your API should return a single node (the root). This root node can contain children which are also nodes that follow NodeInterface. In the above exmaple, rootVisible was set to false so that the root would be hidden.

Comment: okay, and how can i get the local data into the store? I got a textfield (hidden), from there i get my Json